# BestPractices: Is it bad OOP to subclass standard classes into a new one that does same thing, but "presuming" future changes?

Tags: java, android, oop, design-patterns

I have had similar cases in the past, and this is just an example to illustrate:

I'm going to implement a new feature in my android app (but this applies to any kind of OO project), and at this point I need to implement some "action" in the "setVisibility" method from EVERY edittext in EVERY activity I have.

To do it, I have to subclass "EditView", and override "setVisibity" method:

```
@Override
public void setVisibility(int visibility)
{
    super.setVisibility(visibility);
    // --> do my stuff here! <--
}
```

So far, so good... the problem is to change all activities I have (more than 200, and thounsands code lines), and then I think: "*why on earth didn't I start the project subclassing the standard EditText, 'cos I knew some point I'll need to implement something like this*".

That's the point: Is it bad OOP to subclass a "standard class" into a new one that does exaclty same thing, but just "presuming" cases like that? I mean, **subclass everything**, like buttons, activities, etc.

AFAIK, desing pattern and OOP discourage the "presuming factor", but I'd to hear what you guys "do in real life" (or think about that), based on your programming experience.

Also, maybe this type of question ("what you think", "what your oppinion") isn't a good practice here in SO, but I can't find any better place to put it on.

Comment: For the specific case that you need to execute some code for a common method along lot of classes, I would recommend not using inheritance at all but aspect programming. You can enable this by using AspectJ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not bad, and I recommend you always do it on any class you'll reasonably extend over time.  For example in our iOS projects we always start with a UIViewController subclass called ViewControllerBase that does nothing but extend Apple's base class (the same can be said for Activity on Android).

When we need to add something in later that should apply to every view controller (analytics perhaps), it's easy to do.

Fortunately, even if you have a lot of classes in your code it's easy to inject your custom base class with a simple search and replace across your codebase.

Do be careful though as once you have a class that's in everything, small changes can of course have broad and possibly unexpected effects.  Be sure to test thoroughly!

EDIT:

Regarding subclassing *everything*, I'd say no.  You quickly reach a point of diminishing returns on your time and utility.  A common view controller base is pretty standard, as for buttons and so on probably not so much.  It depends entirely on what you want to do that you think might need custom functionality.  If you want to log every user action, then maybe you do want to subclass every control, but in that case it might be better to just log touch events.  At the end of the day though, are you really going to parse all the data that gets generated?  Probably not.  So make sure you have a solid use case before you go crazy subclassing.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of "unexpected effects" and also I use "search/replace" technique, but that's what I'm trying to "not have to do". Good to know your oppinion. thanks.

Comment: But search and replace *is* what you want to do in most cases (which is to say where you've determined the business case for something after you've shipped).  For planning ahead you'll only want to subclass the most obvious common code.

Answer (score 5):

There's no reason to stub out code unless you're actually making changes.  It's wasted effort, and just bloats your codebase.

If you find yourself in a situation where you're repeatedly making the same modification, consider refactoring to share common code.  Or in certain cases, there's merit to *generating* those pieces of code (for example, Avro does this).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion there are some cases in which it makes sense to derive classes of a Framework.
At work we used derived classes for the UI-Elements to have control over their behavior.